# Network places missing in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, networking, wireless-networking

I recently bought a netbook that came with Windows XP. However, "My Network Places" is missing, and there's seemingly no way I can access shared folders on on computer's on the same wireless network.

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that @joeqwerty has your [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/99474/network-places-missing-in-windows-xp/99476#99476), but in case not you might just check to see that the icon hasn't been removed from the desktop.  Right-click on the desktop, select Properties, and have a look:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look and see if the Client for Microsoft Networks and the File and Printer sharing for Microsoft Networks components are installed and bound to your network adapter. Then check to make sure that the Workstation and Server services are running. Also check the Windows Firewall and see if there are any rules prohibiting local network access to file and printer sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Run the network wizard:

Open the Network Connections folder. Under Network Tasks, click **Set up a home or small office network**. Or click Start | All Programs | Accessories | Communications | **Network Setup Wizard**.